# Find a transfinite monotone subsequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, order-theory, cauchy-sequences, ordered-fields

Let $(\mathbb{K},0,1,+,\times,\leq)$ be an ordered field.
Let $\delta$ be its cofinality, *i.e.* the length of the smallest sequence of $\mathbb{K}$ that is cofinal with it. $\delta$ is a regular cardinal.   My question is the following :

---

Given a transfinite sequence in $\mathbb{K}$, $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha<\delta}$, can I extract a subsequence of length $\delta$ that is non-increasing or non-decreasing ?

---

In $\mathbb{R}$ for instance, $\delta=\omega$ (in my purpose I do not make any difference between cardinals and the corresponding ordinals). My statement is the monotone subsequence lemma. I just want a generalization with bigger fields.

I thinks that the fact that $\delta$ is a regular cardinal is important and using that $\delta$ is the cofinality of $\mathbb{K}$ has an important role to play (otherwise I would be able to find an increasing sequence of $\mathbb{R}$ that has an uncountable length). In particular, every dense subset has cardinality at least $\delta$.

As an additional hypothesis, I can assume that every Cauchy-sequence of length
$\delta$ is convergent. Nevertheless $\mathbb{K}$ may not have the least upper bound property.

**Edit** : You can assume that $\mathbb{K}$ is real-closed if you want. I would be happy with it.

Comment: Have you tried using Ramsey theorem with the following 2-coloration :
$(x,y)$ is black if $x < y$, white otherwise?

Comment: Another useful keyword might be "indiscernible sequence". But then you'll probably need to assume that $\mathbb{K}$ is a real closed field.

Comment: @OlivierRoche I thought of that too, but there is no analogue for a two-colour, pairs Ramsey theorem for other cardinals except very large ones (weakly compact)

Comment: @OlivierRoche yes, maybe model theory is the way to go here, expand into an answer?

Comment: @OlivierRoche I don't see why such a coloring would be helpfull. In particular, Ramsey's theorem (infinite version) applies to countable sets...  Here I can have arbitrarily large ones... Actually if $\delta=\omega$ everything becomes trivial, the usual proof applies. If I remember well there some kind of generalizations but I am not so familiar with Ramsey theory... About "indiscernible" sequences, I will investigate it (I want to apply my result to a real closed field so I don't care too add this hypothesis).

Comment: @Quentin The coloring is chosen so that a monochrome sequence is either non-increasing or non-decreasing, which would be nice if we had a version of Ramsey's theorem for cardinal numbers. Sorry...

Comment: @OlivierRoche That's what I thought... The point of my comment was precisely that... Actually I was one of my first idea to try to prove my lemma but since I have a cardinal number I was unable to find a suitable generalization. I also tried something like compacity of propositional calculus but my problem would be express in terms of LTL which has no compacity property...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This property is called $\delta$-Ramsey for $\mathbb{K}$ in the article *Generalized Archimedean fields* by Cowles and LaGrange. It is true for all fields of cofinality $\delta$ if $\delta$ is a weakly compact cardinal (or if $\delta=\omega$). If $\delta$ is not, then it fails in certain fields.

Here is an example for $\delta=\omega_1$; which generalizes to any non weakly compact cardinal. Given an injective sequence $r=(r_{\alpha})_{\alpha<\omega_1}$ of real numbers, there may not be a monotonous subsequence of $r$. This is because this would entail the existence of an injective sequence $(q_{\alpha})_{\alpha<\omega_1}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. Consider the field $\mathbb{R}((X_{\alpha})_{\alpha<\omega_1})$ obtained by adding inductively indeterminates $X_{\alpha}, \alpha<\omega_1$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and imposing $\mathbb{R}((X_{\alpha})_{\alpha<\beta})<X_{\beta}$ for all $\beta<\omega_1$. This has cofinality $\omega_1$ but the sequence $(r_{\alpha})_{\alpha<\omega_1}$ still has no monotonous subsequence in it. This is the same if you take its closure under limis of Cauchy $\omega_1$-sequences.

On the other hand, the field $\mathbb{Q}((X_{\alpha})_{\alpha<\omega_1})$ obtained similarly does have this $\omega_1$-Ramsey property. Cowles and LaGrange (and Sikorski before them) use this property along with the convergence of $\omega_1$-sequences and another property to obtain fields $F$ in which any $\operatorname{cof}(F)$-sequence has a convergent subsequence.

---

Regarding your quesiton about $\mathbf{No}(\delta)$.

$\mathbf{No}(\delta)$ is not Ramsey in general. This has cofinality $\delta$ (the cofinality of a linear order is the unique regular ordinal which embeds cofinally into it).
Assume that there is a cardinal $\kappa <\delta$ with $2^{\kappa}\geq\delta$. This is not too wild an assumption. I choose $\kappa$ minimal, so for $\alpha < \kappa$, we have $2^{\alpha}<\delta$. In particular $\mathbf{No}(\kappa)$ has cardinal $<\delta$ by regularity of $\delta$. Its dense extension $D_{\kappa}$ of numbers in $\mathbf{No}(\kappa+1)$, in whose sign sequence the pattern $(-+)$ or $(+-)$ occurs cofinaly, has cardinal $2^{\kappa}\geq \delta$.
Pick an injective sequence indexed by $\delta$ in $D_{\kappa}$. This does not have a monotonous subsequence, otherwise $\delta$ would order-embed in $\mathbf{No}(\kappa)$ by density, which cannot be by the previous cardinality argument.
So $D_{\alpha} \subset\mathbf{No}(\delta)$, is a counterexample.

You can see that this is a generalization of the argument with real sequences indexed by $\omega_1$.  There may be a simpler argument using a clever sequence of Hahn series, to deal with your other question, but I can't find one for now.

Comment: Thanks for the example ! Actually the fields I'm interested in are quite similar to the one you describe. However I have a new question. Assuming continuum hypothesis (so that you cannot build $(r_\alpha)_{\alpha<\omega_2}$), what about $\mathbb{R}((X_\alpha)_{\alpha<\omega_2})$ ?

Comment: @Quentin: Maybe what you're doing has ties with the article I mentioned? I think your field is $\omega_2$-Ramsey (assuming CH). Elements in this field are rational fractions with indeterminates in $\omega_2$. Fix a function $\omega_2\ni \alpha \mapsto \frac{P_{\alpha}}{Q_{\alpha}}$ ranging in this field. Let $X$ (resp. $Y$) denote the set of ordinals $\alpha$ such that the maximal index occurring in $P$ is strictly greater than (resp. lower than) that occurring in $Q$. Regularity and "largeness" arguments allow you to assume that $X$ or $Y$ has cardinal $\omega_2$, then extract a subsequence.

Comment: @Quentin: Well my scheme or proof does not really work as such but I can elaborate if you want.

Comment: In the article you mentioned there is a theorem that says that a field is $\mathcal{BW}(\delta)$ if and only if it is $\delta$-Archimedean, $\delta$-Cauchy-complete and $\delta$-Ramsey. One particular family of fields I'm interested in contains the Cauchy-competions of  $\delta$-Archimedean fields. But none of them is not $\mathcal{BW}(\delta)$. Then they are not $\delta$-Ramsey.

Comment: The $\delta$-Archimedean field I speak about are basically Hahn-series (bounded in length by some $\epsilon$-number so that we have indeed a field) such that the exponent group is a ring containing ordinals (with naturals operations) less than $\mu$, a multiplicative ordinal. Such a field has cofinality $|\omega^\mu|$. I guess that if $\mathbb{R}((X_\alpha)_{\alpha<\omega_2})$ is indeed Ramsey, so would be my field when $\omega^\mu$ has cardinality $\omega_2$ (for instance for $\mu=\omega_2$)... May be there is something that I miss...

Comment: I am not sure that the Ramsey properties are preserved under Cauchy completions. Would your fields be more succinctly described as fields of surreal numbers?

Comment: That's exactly a surreal number field. After all ,$No(\delta)$ may be Ramsey and his completion not, you are right...  But I would be also happy in this case. I could see that you are familiar with surreal numbers. Do you know if $No(\delta)$ is indeed Ramsey ? More generally $R_{<\lambda}((t^{No(\mu)}))$ ?

Comment: It is easier that I edit my answer with regards to your question.